# reduce method fails unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following method within an Angular component:

```
public mapInvoices(invoices: any[]): Record<string, any> {
    return invoices.reduce((map, obj) => {
      map[obj.letterType] = obj;
      return map;
    }, {});
  }
```

When I run the unit test for this component, I'm getting the following issue:

```
APAUInvoicesDocumentsComponent › should create

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

      37 |
      38 |   public mapInvoices(invoices: any[]): Record<string, any> {
    > 39 |     return invoices.reduce((map, obj) => {
         |                     ^
      40 |       map[obj.letterType] = obj;
      41 |       return map;
      42 |     }, {});
```

I could bypass this issue by assigning a default value to the parameter like:

```
public mapInvoices(invoices: any[] = [])
```

but I would like to understand why this happens.

Comment: Are are you actually _passing_ a value of `invoices` in the test?!

Comment: No, actually I'm not testing that method yet. There is just the default UT (should create)

Comment: Then what _is_ calling that method? Give a [mre].

Comment: That method is called by: <div *ngFor="let item of mapInvoices(invoices) | keyvalue">.     And the invoices are passed as Input in the component ( @Input() invoices: Invoice[];)

Comment: [Edit] the question - where do _you_ think `invoices` is coming from? Give a proper example per the linked help, not just disconnected snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, it is because `mapInvoices` is being called with an `undefined` parameter. By setting a default value you are actually overriding initial state.

```js
public mapInvoices(invoices?: any[] = []) {}
mapInvoices(); // call bombs without a default value
```